# Update Label Text with Timer Values

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I know there are a lot of answers out there about similar issues, but it seems all of them are don't fit to my problem. And I am new to Swift and my head is burning about all this stuff.

The task is very simple. I have a `ViewController` and a Class called "TimeIsTicking", which I defined in a separate `Swift` File. I did this, because I want to feed 5 `ViewController` (which are nested in `TabBarController`) with data from the `Timer` and they all have to run "synchronized".

The function `fireTimer` puts every second the value of 1 to the variable `seconds`.

In the `ViewController` is a `Label` and I want the Label to be updated every time when the timer puts a new value to seconds.

`dayLabelText` gets the data, here is everything fine, but from that point I'm stuck. Label Text isn't been updated.

I suspect, that there has to be a "loop" to reload the data for the Label and I thought the loop in `fireTimer` would be enough but I was obviously wrong.

I tried the "`Observer` Thing" and the "`Dispatchqueue` Thing" but I didn't play well ((obviously).

Help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code of the timer class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TimeIsTicking {
    
    var seconds: Int = 0
    
    static let timeFlow = TimeIsTicking()

    func fireTimer() {
        let finance = FinanceVC()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.seconds += 1
            finance.dayLabelText = "\(self.seconds)"
            print("Seconds: ", self.seconds)
            print("LabelText: ", finance.dayLabelText)   
        }
    }  
}
```

And here is the code of the VieWController:

```
import UIKit

class FinanceVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!
    
    var dayLabelText = String(TimeIsTicking.timeFlow.seconds)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        dayLabel.text = dayLabelText

        TimeIsTicking.timeFlow.fireTimer()
  
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Comment: Please describe your issue.

Comment: The text of the Label in the ViewController doesn't update.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is create a suitable model object to properly track the elapsed time (hint, counting seconds is not a good approach).  Then you need to ensure that a single instance of this model is shared between all view controllers.  Third you need to have the view controllers subscribe to time updates from the model.  You could use `Notification` or `Combine`.  [My article](https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f) might help with the model stuff.  It uses Swift UI to actually display the time, but you can use Combine in your VC

Comment: @Paulw11 Your article is great. Thanks for that. Like I said to meaning-matters, for me as native German all the concepts are YERY HARD to learn because I have to read all these tutorials in foreign language.

Comment: @Paulw11 Your advice with the 'Notification' was VERY useful. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues:

- The `finance` object goes out of scope when `fireTimer()` returns. It will be deallocated then.  The timer will be setting a label text on a no longer existing view controller.
- Instantiating a `UIViewController` with `FinanceVC()` doesn't display it on screen.  After instantiating you need to explicitly show.  You can do this for example by calling [present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) from a parent view controller.
- The timer updates `dayLabelText` which does not update `dayLabel.text`

Might be good to follow a basic YT tutorial on how to display a view controller.

Good luck, you'll get it soon enough!

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. When I try to update dayLabel.text, then I get "nil error while unwrapping". I realized, that this point is ONE issue. BTW It is SO hard to learn all this stuff when your native language is German. All the concepts are hard enough to learn though. Python was much more simpler. :-)